# Problem adding migration in Entity Framework Core on Windows in VM

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition) on Windows on a virtual machine (host OS is Mac OS). I have a .NET 6.0 MVC-project with the follow packages installed:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer *(version 6.0.24)*
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools *(version 6.0.24)*

When I try to run the command `Add-Migration Initial` from the NuGet Package-Manager console, I receive the following error-message:

[image]

However, the file does exist in the location \\Mac\Home\Desktop\Demo EF\bin\Debug\Demo_EF.deps.json

I've already tried to use **dotnet ef** instead, but then I receive the following error:
[image]

I suspect that the error lies in the fact that the first backslashes in the path are doubled, but I'm not sure if and how I could fix this.

Could someone provide me with a solution for this problem please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sometimes deleting the "bin" and "obj" folders inside the projects and rebuilding the solution helps on most cases. Give it a try ;)

Comment: @DanielD: thank you very much for your suggestion. I've tried to rebuild the project multiple times, but without success 